# Char to ASCII in C

Tags: c

I have a homework and I am trying to make this recursion program, but I am wrong somewhere. Tried to contact my teacher but she is out of the country and I feel lost.

About the program:

The user inputs char symbols until he enters '.' and then the program should print on the screen the symbols that were entered, but only if their ASCII code is even.

I did what I had in mind, but somewhere I am going wrong.

The problem is that when I enter  `"10 12 14 33 11 55 7 222 44 2 ."` I get printed `"2 44 222          4 2 0"`. I dont understand am I suppoused to enter numbers since we are talkingabout symbols and second of all why is it printing `"0 2 4"` instead of `"10 12 14"`?

I am really really confused right now. My hope is in you!

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ReversePrint()
{
   char ch='A';
   scanf("%c",&ch);
   if(ch!='.')
   {
      ReversePrint();
      if (ch%2==0)
      {
         printf("%c",ch);
      }
      else
      {
         printf("");
      }
   }
}
int main()
{
   printf("ENTER SYMBOLS:\n");
   ReversePrint();
   printf("\n");
   system("Pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the clue is in the name "ReversePrint"?

Comment: It is not really clear what your program is supposed to do. Can you explain better the goal?

Comment: Can you give an example of something you enter and the result expected?

Comment: @daouzli It must do a recursive function, that prints in reverse order entered by the user symbols until the user enters '.', but only if their ASCII code is even.

Comment: @daouzli for example if I enter "10 12 14 33 11 55 7 222 44 2 ." I must get "2 44 222          14 12 10"

Comment: So if you provide "012345678." you want "86420"?

Comment: @daouzli Exactly! But in that case it is working. the problem is when I type in
"10
 12
 14
"

Comment: @Monster: There s no check for even in your example

Comment: not exactly what I said, you want to consider numbers white space separated, right?

Comment: @daouzli try enter them this way 10(enter) 12(enter) 14(enter) . and you should get 14(row)12(row)10(row)

Comment: You can try the code I posted bellow

Comment: if it's ok for you you can vote and accept my answer mate ;)

Comment: I feel we are mixing up here symbols with numbers. 10 consists of 2 symbols - '1' and '0'. Do you have any example, how SHOULD this program work?

Comment: @Monster so did you fix your problem? did my solution fit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following changes in the code

1. Change the position of the call to the same function
2. Before you check the character, convert it into an integer form and then perform the if..operation on the converted integer

I don't know if that's what you're looking for

Your code will be :-

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

void ReversePrint()
{
   char ch='A';
   **int n;**
   scanf("%c",&ch);
   if(ch!='.')
   {
      **n=ch;**

      if (n%2==0)
      {
         printf("%c",ch);
      }
      else
      {
         printf("");
      }
       **ReversePrint();**
   }
}
int main()
{
    printf("ENTER SYMBOLS:\n");
    ReversePrint();
    printf("\n");
    system("Pause");
    return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: this code doesn't provide the expected result as it doesn't consider the whole number

Answer (score 0):

The program works perfect as I see it.

Every character you enter is output in reverse order, if the ascii code is even. What might confuse you, is that it even outputs the spaces you enter. If you want to exclude non digit characters, you must test for it, e.g.

```
if (ch % 2 == 0 && isdigit(ch)) {
    printf("%c", ch)
}
```

Since in the `else` part nothing happens, you can eliminate it altogether.

If you want to enter and output whole numbers instead of only digits, you might try

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
```

and

```
if (n % 2 == 0) {
    printf("%d", n)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that when I enter "10 12 14 33 11 55 7 222 44 2 ." I
>   get printed "2 44 222 4 2 0".
>   I dont understand am I supposed to
>   enter numbers since we are talking about symbols and second of all why
>   is it printing "0 2 4" instead of "10 12 14"?

That s because each char are checked separately.
44 isn t 44, it s 4, and 4, not 44.

Spaces are a ascii code too, and get printed as such in your program.

You seems to be confused by the difference between Ascii Code and Ascii Symbol, look at a [Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)

In your else, you print nothing, it consume processus time for nothing, you can skip the else altogether.

You can check for space by looking if the char have a value of 32 (decimal), and choose to not print them to have a better output.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will read at most MAX_NUMBERS separated by a white space. The string must finish by a space and a point.

It will read a number and add it to a table, then an other number and add it again, etc until it reach '.'. Then the table numbers are displayed in reverse order only for even numbers.

So for the string `10 12 14 33 11 55 7 222 44 2 .` the output will be `"2 44 222 14 12 10"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NUMBERS 500

int getNumber()
{
   char ch;
   int i, loop = 0, nb = -1;
   char number[4];

   /* Read one number (max 3 chars) */
   i = 0;
   do
   {
      scanf("%c", &ch);
      if (ch != ' ' && ch != '.')
      {
          number[i] = ch;
          i++;
       }
       else 
       {
           loop = 1;
       }
   } while(loop == 0 && i < 4);

   if (ch == '.' || i == 0)
   {
       nb = -1;
   }
   else
   {
       number[i] = '\0';
       nb = atoi(number);
   }
   return nb;
}

int main()
{
    int nb = 0, count, i;
    int numbers[MAX_NUMBERS];
    printf("ENTER SYMBOLS:\n");
    count = 0;
    while(nb > -1 && count < MAX_NUMBERS)
    {
        nb = getNumber();
        /* printf("<%d>", nb); */
        if (nb > -1)
        {
            numbers[count] = nb;
            count++;
        }
    }
    /* reverse printing */
    for (i=0; i < count; i++)
    {
        /* select only even numbers */
        if ((numbers[count - 1 - i] % 2) == 0)
        {
            printf("%d ", numbers[count - 1 - i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Consider that this code is not perfect, it won't check validity of given input, but it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use an int because it is the numerical input of 0-255.

```
void ReversePrint(void){
    int ch;
    if(scanf("%d", &ch)==1){
        ReversePrint();
        if(ch % 2 == 0)
            printf("%d ", ch);
    }
}
```